# Which is faster, XML search or CSV search for word indexes?

Tags: xml, csv

I have 2 files, each having 2 words : "word1" and "word2"

They are

1. An XML

```html
<text>
   <word id="word1">
     <file>File1Name.txt</file>
     <file>File2Name.txt</file>
     <file>File3Name.txt</file>
   </word>
   <word id="word2">
     <file>File1Name.txt</file>
     <file>File4Name.txt</file>
   </word>
</text>
```

2. A CSV File

```
word1, File1Name.txt, File2name.txt, File3Name.txt
word2, File1Name.txt, File4Name.txt
```

Suppose I have 1 million words in both formats and I have to search for one word. Which format would be faster to retrieve  my required files which contain that word?

Comment: this might be worth looking at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224929/is-csv-a-good-alternative-to-xml-and-json

Comment: Already did, and the answer is "it depends". which is why I provided context as to what I wanted to do

Comment: Why would you use XML over JSON?

Comment: @thekevshow: I wanted the code to be a bit more readable, but, if JSON provides faster parsing, then by all means I'm for it. But my concern is the volume of data. If I had to put the entire file into memory and then do the search, wouldnt that be slower? I just want my search to be really really fast.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I wanted to put my two cents here. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch

is something I highly recommend you look into for something like this. I would recommend JSON over either XML or CSV as far as performance. But if you are going to have a million records. Something like document store with a non-relational DB, such as MongoDB would provide you with the fastest result's possible most likely, especially if your data is flat.

Alternatively if this is something you are loading into memory, I would try to use some type of caching solution, let me know if you have more questions. Something like redis might be useful for you. http://redis.io/topics/introduction